# Event for DateTime Controller, when the DateTime Controller is Cleared

Tags: event-handlers, datetimecontrol

I am using a DateTime Controller with an event validator (Required Field). I need to fire an event when a user clears the DateTime Controller (Empty).

I was trying to do this in DateTimeController_DateChanged Event.

But it doesn’t work. Please let me know if there's any other event, that i can use when the DateTime controller gets cleared.

```
protected void LeaveStartDateTimeControl_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetupLeaveApplicationDetails();

        this.SubmitButton.Enabled = true;

        if (!this.LeaveStartDateTimeControl.IsDateEmpty)
        {
            this.AvailableBalanceLabel.Text = this.PopulateLeaveBalance(this.EmployeeNoTextBox.Text,
                    this.CompanyDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text, this.LeaveStartDateTimeControl.SelectedDate,
                    this.LeaveTypeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower());
        }
        else 
        {
            this.AvailableBalanceLabel.Text = string.Empty; 
        }
    }
```